# Printing multiple exceptions of method called

Tags: java, exception

I am implementing a compiler type checker in Java. My `typeChecking` class consists of methods that throw `RuntimeExceptions` if the given input file (program) is semantically wrong.

What happens now is when my program finds an error, it throws the exception and the program terminates. The functionality I want is to keep somewhere all the exception messages and print them at my `Main` class if an exception occurred at the `typeChecking` class.

Pseudocode example:

```
// Main class part of code
public static void main(String[] args){

    call typeChecking method

    if an exception (or more) occurred in the typeChecking class
        then print all the exception messages
    else no semantic errors found
        then do something else
}
```

What I thought is to create a static `String` array and add all the exception messages in it. Then at my `Main` class I am going to check if the array's size is 0. If it is not, this means exceptions occurred else not.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Very interesting question this is. On the one hand side, you want to do "compiler" work; which is often seen as pretty advanced topic in software engineering. On the other hand; you suggest to do "real stuff" in your main method. The later somehow indicates ... that you don't know much yet about good design. So, unless this is some "homework" project; I actually recommend you to step back and first learn about OO design (for example checking out the "SOLID" rules by Fowler) before diving into topics like compiler construction.

Comment: Exception may be a wrong way to report a problem, anyway. You can't have "(or more)"  exceptions. May be returning a list of objects containing information about one or more errors found is a better way.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do a "catch and continue" with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use try-catch block to catch exceptions and do whatever you want with caught exception. I.e.

```
// Main class part of code
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean exceptionOccured = false;
    try{
        call typeChecking method
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        exceptionOccured = true;
        ...print it or put in an array or whatever.
    }
    if(exceptionOccured)
        do something else
}
```

Comment: Won't this interrupt the typeChecking method? I want it to keep running in order to find the other errors

Comment: @pirox22 if something throws an exception, it is interrupted, you cannot stop it.